# SQL - Previous order date per row

Tags: sql, date, row, min

I have two tables:

- Order (order_id, client_id, order_date)
- Client (client_id)

where clients can have many orders

**What I need is a previous_order(date) column per row**

Example:

```
order_id | order_date | order_client | previous_order
-----------------------------------------------------
    1    | 02/02      |      1       | null
    2    | 02/03      |      1       | 02/02
    3    | 02/10      |      1       | 02/03
    4    | 02/10      |      1       | 02/10
```

I tried this command:

select a.*, b.previous_date from order a

join (select a.order_client, min(a.order_date) as previous_date from order a

group by a.order_client) b

on a.order_client = b.order_client

But using this i get the first order of each client.

I also saw lag() and lead() functions. But they are not avaiable in the microsoft sql server 10.50

Can anyone help me with this SQL command?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question to demonstrate things you've already tried.

Comment: sippy, you are right...done!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Client (Client_ID INT )
CREATE TABLE #Order (Order_ID INT, Client_ID INT, Order_Date DATE)  
INSERT INTO #Client
         ( Client_ID )
VALUES
         ( 1 ) -- Client_ID - int

INSERT INTO #Order
         ( Order_ID, Client_ID, Order_Date )
VALUES
         ( 1 , 1 , '20150202' ),
         ( 2 , 1 , '20150203' ),
         ( 3 , 1 , '20150210' ),
         ( 4 , 1 , '20150210' )

SELECT 
     Order_ID AS order_id
   , Order_Date AS order_date
   , Client_ID AS order_client
   , (SELECT MAX(Ord2.Order_Date) 
      FROM #Order AS Ord2 
      WHERE 
          Ord2.Order_Date <= #Order.Order_Date 
      AND Ord2.Order_ID < #Order.Order_ID 
      AND Ord2.Client_ID = #Order.Client_ID) AS previous_order
FROM #Order 

-- Cleanup
DROP TABLE #Client
DROP TABLE #Order
```

Comment: lifesaver! i only changed the '<= #Order.Order_Date' for '< #Order.Order_Date'